# How to use autotools nobase and nodist prefixs together on include_HEADERS

Tags: c, autotools, automake

I have some header files in a sub directory, that must be copied to a same-named sub directory in my include directory. I can use the nobase prefix to make that happen (I'm working with heimdal code, fyi):

```
nobase_include_HEADERS = hcrypto/aes.h \
      hcrypto/bn.h      \
      hcrypto/cmac.h    \
      hcrypto/des.h     \
      hcrypto/dh.h      \
      hcrypto/dsa.h     \
etc...
```

But some of those header files are generated during the build process (since heimdal must be built before those header files exist), so I need to use the nodist prefix so that the dist doesn't die.

[I found an article](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/automatically_writing_makefiles_with_autotools) that said I could use them both together, and even provided a similar example, so I did this:

```
nobase_nodist_include_HEADERS = hcrypto/aes.h \
      hcrypto/bn.h      \
      hcrypto/cmac.h    \
      hcrypto/des.h     \
      hcrypto/dh.h      \
      hcrypto/dsa.h     \
etc...
```

I didn't notice any warnings or errors, but those header files DO NOT get copied to my include directory.
Am I doing something wrong, or is there a bug in autotools?

Interesting, if I reverse the prefixes, I get this error:

```
Makefile.am:93: error: 'nodist_nobase_include_HEADERS' is used but 'nobase_includedir' is undefined
```

The reason for that error is explained here in the [automake documentation](https://gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Alternative):

> ‘nobase_’ should be specified first when used in conjunction with either ‘dist_’ or ‘nodist_’

I've also defined nodist_include_HEADERS (which is working). Maybe the two definitions are causing some kind of conflict?

I just tried removing the nodist_include_HEADERS and putting all my headers under the nobase_nodist_include_HEADERS line, but now NONE of my headers get installed.

Automake and system info:
automake (GNU automake) 1.13.4 openSUSE 13.2 (x86_64)

Comment: please add any additional information to the question itself, rather than abusing some comments.

Comment: Please, make a mimimal complete working example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  (A small collection of Makefile.am in your case)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the headers were generated by a program, you should mark them with `BUILT_SOURCES`, this way `automake` will not be confused to try to install them as `dist`.

Second, for headers files that are not meant to be installed, it's better to use `SOURCES` directive, rather than `HEADERS`. Try this:

```
nobase_include_SOURCES += hcrypto/aes.h \
    hcrypto/bn.h      \
    hcrypto/cmac.h    \
    hcrypto/des.h     \
    hcrypto/dh.h      \
    hcrypto/dsa.h
BUILT_SOURCES = hcrypto/aes.h \
    hcrypto/bn.h      \
    hcrypto/cmac.h    \
    hcrypto/des.h     \
    hcrypto/dh.h      \
    hcrypto/dsa.h
```

Comment: Question: BUILT_SOURCES seems can still be installed and distributed by default. If you are dealing with a source that is simply packaged and distributed in another format, such as a generated python script xx.py that is simple packaged independently with setup.py utility.  I want to avoid the distribution and installation of xx.py, how to you add nodist_ Here we have no include_SOURCES.